# How to change the color based on text in excel using Python?

Tags: python, xlwt

In Excel cell text will vary from Pass to Fail.I have to give background color green for Pass(pass/Passed/passed) and red for Fail(fail/Failed/failed) respectively. How to change the color based on text ?

### My Script

```
import xlwt

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Testing')
worksheet.write_merge(5, 5, 1, 1,'S.No')
worksheet.write_merge(5, 5, 2, 2,'Test Case Description')
worksheet.write_merge(5, 5, 3, 3,'Status')
worksheet.write_merge(5, 5, 4, 4,'Remarks')
worksheet.write_merge(6, 6, 1, 1,1)
worksheet.write_merge(7, 7, 1, 1,1)
worksheet.write_merge(6, 6, 2, 2,'Verify Transferring rate')
worksheet.write_merge(7, 7, 2, 2,'Verify Receiving rate')
worksheet.write_merge(6, 6, 3, 3,'Pass')
worksheet.write_merge(7, 7, 3, 3,'Fail')
workbook.save('testexcel.xls')
```

@Henry:

### Modified code :

```
import xlwt
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Status')

passed = xlwt.easyxf('back_color green')
failed = xlwt.easyxf('back_color red')


color = (passed if passorfail in ['pass','Passed','passed'] else
    (failed if passorfail in ['fail','Failed','failed'] else xlwt.easyxf()))

worksheet.write_merge(6, 6, 3, 3,passorfail, style = color)

workbook.save('passfail2.xls')
print "Completed"
```

And it's throwing error when execute ? How to resolve this error ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\airspan_eclipse\Excel_Gen\passfail2.py", line 5, in <module>
    passed = xlwt.easyxf('back_color green')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Style.py", line 704, in easyxf
    field_sep=field_sep, line_sep=line_sep, intro_sep=intro_sep, esc_char=esc_char, debug=debug)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Style.py", line 632, in _parse_strg_to_obj
    raise EasyXFCallerError('line %r should have exactly 1 "%c"' % (line, intro_sep))
xlwt.Style.EasyXFCallerError: line 'back_color green' should have exactly 1 ":"
```

Comment: If an answer resolves your problem, may I suggest you accept it? If you have further problems, please post them as separate questions.

Comment: As for the error you see, you need to add "pattern:" to the style specification. Example: `xlwt.easyxf('pattern: back_color green')`

Comment: @Dhara Sure I accepted the answer

Comment: @Dhara after fixing ('pattern: back_color green') thsi am getting below error :                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\airspan_eclipse\Excel_Gen\passfail2.py", line 9, in <module>
    color = (passed if passorfail in ['pass','Passed','passed'] else
NameError: name 'passorfail' is not defined

Comment: That's because the 2nd answer assumed you have a variable called passorfail that holds the status, instead of hard-coded "Pass"/"Fail" strings. If you don't have that, obviously the solution is not going to work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can create styles using [easyxf](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966) and then pass them as arguments to your write method.

For example:

```
style_pass = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour green;')
style_fail = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour red;')
worksheet.write_merge(6, 6, 3, 3,'Pass', style=style_pass)
worksheet.write_merge(7, 7, 3, 3,'Fail', style=style_fail)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dhara.The above code works well with my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put in a if statement to seperate pased on pass fail.

Then, you'll use that to make a color string, something like `'fore-colour grey25'`. Look in Style.py for lists of all possible colors and options (github page: https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/Style.py). Since `red` and `green` both work, and `back_color` also works, you can do:

```
passed = xlwt.easyxf('back_color green')
failed = xlwt.easyxf('back_color red')

color = (passed if passorfail in ['pass','Passed','passed'] else
    (failed if passorfail in ['fail','Failed','failed'] else xlwt.easyxf()))
worksheet.write_merge(6, 6, 3, 3,passorfail, style = color)
```